# Can't access Node behind firewall (despite rules)

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, openwrt, node.js, cors

This is a similar but different query to another question I asked back in 2019. I thought it sufficiently different to break out into a new question.

I have written a Node Express app, which uses CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). I'm still trying to develop remotely (SSH to the server). VS Code is working well for that and I can SSH into the server and router (OpenWRT) for admin.

When I run the app, it tells me it's running. Using Links (command line browser) via SSH to the server, I can see the JSON response, so I know it's running.

I have run `export PORT=8080` which is now correctly picked up by the code

The app code is:

```
// Based on a // Tutorial from https://www.bezkoder.com/react-node-express-mysql/ converted to access database of solar power generation values
const express   = require("express");
const cors      = require("cors");
const HOSTNAME  = '0.0.0.0';
const PORT      = process.env.PORT || 8082;
const app       = express();

// const db = require("./app/models");
// db.sequelize.sync();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: `http://${HOSTNAME}:${PORT}`
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8082;

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: `Welcome to Greg's application on localhost: ${PORT}.` });
});

// set port, listen for requests
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port:- ${PORT}.`);
});
```

For some reason, it's picking up the fallback port 8082, from `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8082;`, not the one specified in
`var corsOptions = { origin:` http://${HOSTNAME}:8080 `};`

If I run `curl -v -X -H http://<my static WAN IP>:8082/` from my remote terminal.
I get `No route to host` - see DNAT rule, below

If I run `curl -v -X -H http://<localhost> or <0.0.0.0>:8082/` from my server terminal via ssh.
I get

```
*   Trying ::1:8082...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8082 (#0)
> -H / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

I believe I've set up a DNAT routing rule for port forwarding correctly (I've got three rules. One for each of 8080,8081 & 8082, for the purposes of experimenting) - edited
(see also OpenWRT [link](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/firewall_configuration) for spec and [link](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/understanding-list-vs-option-in-firewall/77868) for explanation of 'option' vs 'list')

```
config redirect
        option dest_port '8080'
        option src 'wan'
        option name 'Tranq8080'
        option src_dport '8080'
        option target 'DNAT'
        option proto 'tcp'
        option dest_ip '<server's LAN address>'
        option dest 'lan'
```

I cannot find a way to access the app's http remotely. I don't know if it's the firewall, the code or some sort of cross scripting voodoo in the browser (the remote CURL refusal I think indicates it's  not the latter)?

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason, it's picking up the fallback port 8082, from `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8082;`, not the one specified in `var corsOptions = { origin: http://${HOSTNAME}:8080 };`

My guess is that `process.env` is checking environment variables, and `POST` isn't defined in the environment that the process is running in, hence defaulting to `8082`. For consistency, I'd define `const PORT` above your `corsOptions` and use the `PORT` variable that's found inside `corsOptions`. If you want it to use `8080` then set the `PORT` environment variable to `8080`. But that's a side issue to the question at hand.

> If I run `curl -v -X -H http://<my static WAN IP>:8082/` from my remote terminal. I get `No route to host` - see DNAT rule, below
>
> ...
>
> I cannot find a way to access the app's http remotely. I don't know if it's the firewall, the code or some sort of cross scripting voodoo in the browser (the remote CURL refusal I think indicates it's not the latter)?

Curl's `No route to host` indicates that it's a routing issue, and thus most likely a problem with the router's DNAT rules. If it were a CORS issue, you'd still get a response back from the server; just one indicating there's a CORS problem.

I'm not familiar with OpenWRT's syntax for port forwarding, but your rules look similar to one example found [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/fw3_nat) for forwarding SSH on port 2222 on the WAN side to port 22 on the LAN side:

```
config redirect
       option target          DNAT
       option src             wan
       option dest            lan
       option proto           tcp
       option src_dport       2222
       option dest_ip         192.168.10.20
       option dest_port       22
       option enabled         1
```

The only difference I can see between that example and your setup is the `list proto 'udp'` and `list proto 'tcp'` entries. I'm assuming that the Express server is using HTTP and as such, only TCP traffic will be involved. What happens if you update your DNAT rules to use `option proto 'tcp'` instead of those `list` lines?

**Edit:**

As per comments, upon updating the NAT config, the host became reachable, but there was a firewall on the host preventing access on ports `8080` through `8082`. Updating the host's firewall rules permitted access.

Comment: Thanks @PrestonManess I made the suggested edits (`export PORT=8080`, which does now get picked up by the code, I explicitly create a `PORT` variable, from `process.env.PORT` and I've cleaned up the firewall port-forward rules to include `option proto 'tcp'` (excludes `udp` and avoids `list` instead of `option`

Comment: Still `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server`

Comment: Incidentally, I just tried `curl` again. 

*From remote with my static IP: `Connection refused`

*From Server with my static IP: `No route to host`

*From server with 0.0.0.0: `Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> -H / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: So now when you connect remotely with the static IP, you get `Connection refused` instead of `No route to host`? That sounds like the server behind the router might also be running its own firewall then and the `8080` through `8082` ports aren't open on it (though, presumably, port `22` would be open on it so you can SSH into it). Does the server have a firewall enabled on it? Like `iptables` or `firewalld`?

Comment: Yessss! I don't usually have the firewall 'on' on that machine, so it didn't even occur to me but I'd upgraded recently and obvs the default was firewall 'on'!

Comment: Thanks for your help Preston